# Auth.federatedSignIn does not give me an authenticated user on redirect

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

So whenever my page is accessed, I check if the user is authenticated using this snipper

```
 try {
       user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
     } 
catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        user = undefined;
           }
```

This works fine when the user logs in manually with email and password, since the log in is successful, the user is redirected to this page, where we check if it is authenticated.

The problem is when I try to use federated sign ins, in which the user redirected to this page after a successful log in is not actually authenticated according to Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser. But it works if I refresh the page, how can it be?

Comment: Have you tried using the Hub event listener as described here? https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/js#setup-frontend

Comment: Yes at the moment I'm using a workaround that involves reloading the page every time a signin event occurs, but there must be a cleaner way to achieve this...